# Fare calculator for any entity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on creating a booking fare calculator.

There are `28` bus stations,

Base Price is `100` up to `5` bus stations.

Later `50` extra for every `5` bus stations.

Single trip from `1 to 28` is `300`.

Here is my solution,

```
BASE = 100
stops = (start - end).abs

case stops
when 1..5
  BASE
when 5..10
  BASE + 5
when 10..15
  BASE + 10
when 15..16
  BASE + 15
when (station_array.length - 1)..station_array.length
  200
end
```

I was looking for a good optimised and scalable solution.
Suppose if, we add new stations, the fare logic should require minimal changes.

Comment: What are the rules for 2000 stations? Is it always +5 for each 5 stations? You mention _"later 50 extra"_ but it's unclear when / where that applies because `50` doesn't occur in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with just basic math, this can work as an example for you to build on.

> Later 50 extra for every 5 bus stations.

This is a bit unclear, is the extra fare calculated after 5 extra stations or already on the first extra?

e.g. is it?

```
A: 6 stations = BASE_FARE + EXTRA_FARE
# or...
B: 6 stations = BASE_FARE only
```

You can remove the `ceil` method if you only want to calculate extra fares after 5 stations, the way I do it here is extra stations 1-4 already add the extra fare.

As to the round trip, you can just add an extra check to see if stations = total_stations

```rb
TOTAL_STATIONS = 500
ROUNDFARE = 300 # or whatever

BASE_PRICE = 100
BASE_STATIONS = 5

EXTRA_PRICE = 50
EXTRA_STATIONS = 5

def calc_price(stations)
  return ROUNDFARE if stations = TOTAL_STATIONS
  total_price = base_price

  # Substract the 5 base stations
  stations -= BASE_STATIONS

  # Add 50 for every 5 stations
  # to_f is used so it does float division
  # ceil is used to round up, e.g. 3 / 5 => 1
  total_price += (stops / EXTRA_STATIONS.to_f).ceil * EXTRA_PRICE

  total_price
end
```

Comment: Just a note, this is not tested thoroughly, this is posted as something for you to build on.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, we can use the hash for this scenario.

```
BASE = 100
stops = (start - end).abs
price_for = {(1..5) => BASE,(6..10) => BASE+5,(11..15) => BASE+10 ..... }

eg: price_for[(1..5)] o/p => 100
```

Like the above scenario, we can easily add new fares and send them also as an object.